# Why is it not possible to directly access property of object in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to access a property I stored in an object in TypeScript.

I created this function to get the specific data from my a JSON object:

```js
public get(): object {
    var temp: any = {};
    this.objectFromClass.forEach((forecast: any, index: number) => {
      if (something) {
        temp = {
          index: index,
          data: data.someData,
        };
      }
      index++;
    });
    return temp;
}
```

And just for simplicity I made a function for just getting the `index`:

```js
public getIndex() {
    return this.get().index;
}
```

Then it gives me an error:

```
Property 'index' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)
```

And for some strange reason it works perfectly like this:

```js
public getIndex() {
    var arr: any = {};
    arr = this.get();
    var index: any = arr.index;

    return index;
}
```

Why is this, am I missing something very obvious? I have tried to look at some similar questions on StackOverflow, but I cannot find any answers to this.

Please point me in the right direction! :)

Comment: The `object` type has no known properties so indexing into it directly is considered an error.  The `any` type is intentionally assignable both to and from any type and also does not complain when you index into it.  Ideally your code would use neither `any` nor `object` to represent types you care about, but that involves some more work.  If you edit your code to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) someone might be able to help with specifics.

Comment: is this.getNow(); is incorrectly equivelent to the function get() ; you could try return <any>this.getNow().index; also it will be good to write forEach((forcast, index) => instead of defining a new variable index

Comment: @AdamNorman Thanks, I added the fix for `forEach` and it works great!

I just tried to add `return <any>this.getNow().index;`, but still the same result...

Comment: Are you followed @jcalz suggest? to replace public get(): object  with public get(): any

Comment: Damn, I didn't get that they meant that from what they said... thanks for pointing it out AdamNorman.

And thank you @jcalz for the solution to my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jcalz and @AdamNorman, I got it to work properly.

By updating the start of my `get()`-function, to `public get(): any` works perfectly!

So now I have

```js
public get(): any {
    var temp: any = {};
    this.objectFromClass.forEach((forecast: any, index: number) => {
      if (something) {
        temp = {
          index: index,
          data: data.someData,
        };
      }
      index++;
    });
    return temp;
}
```